A Coin with Changing Probabilities : When do you see the First Head?
Here is a coin flipping game I thought of involving a coin with changing probabilities:

Initialize: Set lambda=5, p=0.5, set=1, and generate num_flips from Poisson(lambda).
For each set: Do the following until heads is observed:

For each flip in num_flips: Generate a random number between 0 and 1.

If random number < p, record “Heads”, return results, and stop.
Else, record “Tails”, and halve p.




If no heads: Set lambda=num_flips, generate new num_flips from Poisson(lambda), reset p=0.5, increment set, and go to Step 2.

In mathematical terms, we can represent this game as follows:

Initialization:
$$\lambda_0 = 5$$
$$p_0 = 0.5$$
$$s = 1$$
$$n_0 \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda_0)$$

For each set $s$, and for each flip $i$ from 1 to $n_{s-1}$:
$$X_{s,i} \sim \text{Uniform}(0, 1)$$
$$Y_{s,i} = \begin{cases} 
\text{Heads} & \text{if } X_{s,i} < p_{s,i-1} \\
\text{Tails} & \text{if } X_{s,i} \geq p_{s,i-1}
\end{cases}$$


$$p_{s,i} = \begin{cases}
p_{s,i-1} & \text{if } Y_{s,i} = \text{Heads} \\
\frac{p_{s,i-1}}{2} & \text{if } Y_{s,i} = \text{Tails}
\end{cases}$$

If no Heads observed in set $s$:
$$\lambda_s = n_{s-1}$$
$$n_s \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda_s)$$
$$p_{s+1,0} = 0.5$$
$$s = s + 1$$

The process stops when:
$$Y_{s,i} = \text{Heads}$$



$s$ represents the set number
$i$ represents the flip number within a set
$\lambda_s$ is the Poisson parameter for set $s$
$n_s$ is the number of flips in set $s$
$p_{s,i}$ is the probability of Heads for the $i$-th flip in set $s$
$X_{s,i}$ is the random number generated for the $i$-th flip in set $s$
$Y_{s,i}$ is the result (Heads or Tails) of the $i$-th flip in set $s$

I wrote an R simulation for this problem:
flipCoinPoissonTimes <- function() {
    lambda <- 5  # initial parameter for the Poisson distribution
    num_flips <- rpois(1, lambda)  # generate a random number from a Poisson distribution
    
    p <- 0.5  # initial probability of heads
    set <- 1  # initial set number
    results <- data.frame(set=integer(), turn_number=integer(), value_of_p=numeric(), result=character(), lambda=numeric(), num_flips=integer())
    
    while(TRUE) {
        for (turn_number in 1:num_flips) {
            flip <- runif(1)  # generate a random number between 0 and 1
            if (flip < p) {
                results <- rbind(results, data.frame(set=set, turn_number=turn_number, value_of_p=p, result="Heads", lambda=lambda, num_flips=num_flips))
                return(results)  # stop once the first head is observed
            } else {
                results <- rbind(results, data.frame(set=set, turn_number=turn_number, value_of_p=p, result="Tails", lambda=lambda, num_flips=num_flips))
                p <- p / 2  # reduce the probability of heads by half
            }
        }
        # if no heads were observed in this set, generate a new Poisson random number centered around the previous num_flips
        lambda <- num_flips
        num_flips <- rpois(1, lambda)
        p <- 0.5  # reset the probability of heads
        set <- set + 1  # increment the set number
    }
}


results <- flipCoinPoissonTimes()
print(results)

The output looks like this:
   set turn_number value_of_p result lambda num_flips
1    1           1  0.5000000  Tails      5         7
2    1           2  0.2500000  Tails      5         7
3    1           3  0.1250000  Tails      5         7
4    1           4  0.0625000  Tails      5         7
5    1           5  0.0312500  Tails      5         7
6    1           6  0.0156250  Tails      5         7
7    1           7  0.0078125  Tails      5         7
8    2           1  0.5000000  Tails      7         6
9    2           2  0.2500000  Tails      7         6
10   2           3  0.1250000  Tails      7         6
11   2           4  0.0625000  Tails      7         6
12   2           5  0.0312500  Tails      7         6
13   2           6  0.0156250  Tails      7         6
14   3           1  0.5000000  Tails      6         6
15   3           2  0.2500000  Heads      6         6

I am interested in the following questions:

On average,  how many total times do you have to flip the coin before you see the first heads?
When you do see your first heads, what will be the average value of : set, turn_number, value_of_p, lambda, num_flips?
Suppose you have played this game and you are currently at (set = i, turn_number = j, value_of_p = p, lambda=k, num_flips = l) : how many more turns are needed for the game to end (i.e. first head)? what will be the average values of (set, turn_number, value_of_p, lambda, num_flips) conditional on (no heads & set = i, turn_number = j, value_of_p = p, lambda=k, num_flips = l)?

I can repeat this simulation many times and take the averages of the results of all simulations to answer these questions - but I was wondering there is some mathematical way to solve this?

As $N_s \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda_s)$, $\Pr{N_s = 0} =  e^{-\lambda_s} > 0$
What happen when $N_s = 0$ occur? Does the game immediately stop without getting a head?
